# How can I make a newly installed package not to use cached version of another package?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, huggingface-transformers, python-importlib

Title sounds too complicated but it goes like this. I'm using Kaggle notebook for a competition. I implemented an inference pipeline using external packages. Environment doesn't have internet connection. Packages I'm having trouble with are `transformers` and `open_clip`.

Default version of `transformers` is `4.26` on Kaggle. I install a different branch of version `4.18` for model A like this.

```
!pip install ./packages/sacremoses-0.0.53
!pip install ./packages/transformers-4.18.0.dev0-py3-none-any.whl --find-links /packages
```

This version of `transformers` is installed and I use model A for inference without any problem. Then I want to use another model B from `open_clip` which is compatible with `transformers` version `4.27`.

```
!pip install ./packages/transformers-4.27.3-py3-none-any.whl --no-index --find-links ./packages
!pip install ./packages/open_clip_torch-2.16.0-py3-none-any.whl --no-index --find-links ./packages
```

Both of the packages get successfully installed. I had another issue at this point regarding old `transformers` version (`4.18`) was getting cached. I verified it by printing `transformers.__version__` which was `4.18` even though it was `4.27` on pip list. In order to import newer version of `transformers` I added this code block.

```
try:
    import importlib
    importlib.reload(transformers)
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    import transformers
```

It throws an error like this `cannot import name 'OptionalDependencyNotAvailable' from 'transformers.utils' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/utils/__init__.py)`, but it kinda solves this issue. Transformers version becomes `4.27` when I print `transformers.__version__`. However, `open_clip` is still using `transformers` version `4.18` even though it is `4.27` on both `pip list` and `transformers.__version__`.

I tried reloading `open_clip` but it didn't work. Is there way to fix this without killing the kernel?

Edit: I think I made some progress. If I don't import anything from transformers 4.18, there won't be any problem with transformers 4.27. I tried to delete everything I used from transformers 4.18 but it didn't work.

Comment: IMO, I think the time you spent on messing around `importlib` might be better spent on fixing multiple dependencies or thinking of other ways to ensemble your model =)

Comment: The cache will load the old models in the updated transformer version, by default since they share the same cache_directory. Possibly you'll need to remap the cache directory using `snapshot_download` for the models individually.

Comment: Hahaha you are right. I spent too much time on a trivial a thing for an ML competition. I already gave up.